# How can I stop vue cli3 build from including vue.js.min in my chunk-vendors.js file?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I'm starting from scratch and using the default create project from vue using cli 3. Everything is fine, however I noticed the chunk-vendors.js file contains vue.js.min. I don't want to include that file, how do I tell the vue to not include it in production builds?

Comment: Why don't you want to include that file? it is considered a vendor.

Comment: This is true and I understand the purpose but I'm creating several different controls on top of using vuejs in the parent page. I don't want to download vue.js.min for each control. I just load vue.js.min once up front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to exclude Vue from being bundled, use the [library build target](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html).

> In lib mode, Vue is externalized. This means the bundle will not bundle Vue even if your code imports Vue. If the lib is used via a bundler, it will attempt to load Vue as a dependency through the bundler; otherwise, it falls back to a global Vue variable.

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe I missed that page in the docs. Thanks!